# ¿Por qué WorkManager deja de funcionar?

Tags: android, service-workers

Tengo una clase en android que extiende a Worker para mandar notificaciones aun cuando la aplicación se quite de la lista de espera ejecutándose cada 5 minutos. Cuando muestro la notificación enseguida vuelva a ejecutar un nuevo OneTimeWorkRequest con  ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, funciona muy bien por determinado tiempo y después ya no sale ninguna notificación hasta que vuelvo abrir la aplicación.

```
private void DoResetWorkHandler() {
    Constraints constraint = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

    Data socioData = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("ClubSocio",Socio)
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest refreshWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerHandler.class)
            .setConstraints(constraint)
            .addTag("workhandler")
            .setInputData(socioData)
            .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(currentContext).enqueueUniqueWork("workhandler", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, refreshWork);
}
```

Este es el método que mando a llamar para resetear WorkManager cada vez que envio la notificación. Pero después de un tiempo revisando el Logcat dice WorkHandler: Timeout siendo esta la clase que extiende a worker y contiene el método.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es importante revisa el LogCat, se muestra algún error? revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: en el LogCat me pone E/WorkerHandler: timeout , WorkerHandler es mi clase

Comment: y cual es el código, recuerda que en el sitio debes agregar lo que trataste para darnos una idea de que realizas

Comment: Crees que puedas apoyarme con algun comentario?, tambien he usado  PeriodicWorkRequest con un intervalo de 15 minutos pero pasa lo mismo que despues de un tiempo ya deja de funcionar hasta abrir nuevamente la aplicación